# Create Object by Constructor in Object Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have following Address object:

```
public class AddressObject
{
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public AddressObject(string PostCodeString, string CityName, string StreetName)
    {
        Postcode = PostCodeString;
        City = CityName;
        Street = StreetName;
    }

    public AddressObject(string PostCodeString, string CityName)
    {
        Postcode = PostCodeString;
        City = CityName;
    }

    public AddressObject() { }
}
```

And the following fluent mapping I would like to use based on the constructor above:

`Map(x => x.AddressObject).Column("PostCode", "Name").Not.LazyLoad();`

Is there a way to use object constructors inside of a fluent mapping class?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> ...NHibernate requires that all public properties of an entity class are declared as virtual. It also requires a parameter-less constructor: if you add a constructor having parameters, make sure to add a parameter-less constructor too. ([ref](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-persistentclass))

Answer (score -1):

No there is not! Why do you like to act like this?

First of all, you miss the virtual key word on your properties of `AddressObject`.

Secondly the Map-Method maps values per column, so no entity is mapped but a single value (string, enum, int, etc).

If you want to reference `AddressObject` out of another model you have to use 
`Reference(x => ...`.

Comment: okay yes. But I have an atomic table layout means that I am referencing all values with IDs like the postalcode and cityname. That means that I am storing the names in a different table. And if I do a a Reference then nHibernate says that it couldn't Reference a unmapped type String. Which is the type of the postalcode or cityname inside my AddressObject...